# How to connect from a kubernetes cluster to local PostgreSQL database?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

How can I connect from an application that runs inside a pod in a Kubernetes cluster (minikube) to a local database (installed locally, not running in docker)?

Comment: See [Host access](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/host-access/) in the Minikube documentation.  Also consider whether it will be more straightforward to run your database in its own StatefulSet, and keep everything inside the cluster.

Comment: For some reason I cannot connect to host.minikube.internal. If I check the /etc/hosts from minikube I see this strange entry: <nil> host.minikube.internal. Is that <nil> normal? Also ping returns service not known.

Comment: Refer to this  [stack link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66023715) which  can help  you to resolve your issue.